# HTML Form with a PHP post to .txt

Tags: php, html, forms

I know this is repetitive but i do not know PHP at all.. And trying to learn in a time crunch is not working how can i post to a text file? This is what i tried and i get an internal server error...

```
    <div id="signupform" class="sb-search clearfix">
    <form method="post" id="contact" class="clearfix" action="/comingsoon/php/formfix.php" name="email">
        <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter email ..." type="text" value="" name="email">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" value="" type="submit" name="email">
        <button class="formbutton" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is the PHP formfix.php...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $file = fopen("/comingsoon/json.txt",);
    fwrite($file,$email);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong...

Comment: what error it display?

Comment: @fiidoFirdauz Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: You are missing the `$mode` of [`resource fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) -> `$file = fopen("/comingsoon/json.txt",);`. Notice the `,`. Without the `'w'` it will produce a syntax error.

Comment: @RajaSharma already fix the problem. :) Hope this helpful.

Comment: @RajaSharma Is this thread close or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to fix your PHP post to TXT

HTML

```
<div id="signupform" class="sb-search clearfix">
        <form method="post" id="contact" class="clearfix" action="comingsoon/php/formfix.php"> <!-- I remove name="email"-->
            <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter email ..." type="text" value="" name="email">
            <input class="sb-search-submit" value="" type="submit" name="email1">
            <button class="formbutton" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

In your formfix.php should be like this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email1'])) {
    $data = $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['email1'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('json.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}

?>
```

And you will get this result

I already do a test and it's work

[image]

Take a note please be aware on file location. And json.txt path must be at formfix.php .

Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my English is not good, but I will try to explain is to you as my best.

You should alter your HTML like this:

```
<div id="signupform" class="sb-search clearfix">
<form method="post" id="contact" class="clearfix" action="/comingsoon/php/formfix.php">
    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter email ..." type="text" name="email">
    <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" >
</form>
```

A name of this "submit" isn't necessary。And so is the form。

Then，your PHP file should look like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $file = fopen("/comingsoon/json.txt",);
    fwrite($file,$email);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
```

Because the data that post to your server is only "email".

Good Luck to you!